# Losing mirrored queues

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ cluster of 3 nodes that has mirror-all [HA policies defined](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html). Cluster has faulted and partitioned into independent nodes. Cluster was repaired, and as a result of failure some of the queues were lost. Is this a possible scenario even though HA policy to mirror all queues is in place?

Comment: A couple of questions need to be clarified. Are the queues durable? Did you lose messages or whole queue definitions? Do you have cluster_partition_handling setup or you use the default _ignore_? Do you have ram nodes or just disc nodes? If you lost queues when were they created, during clustering or before?

Comment: A different problem was causing this behavior. Still very valuable info, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short yes, but it would be nice to understand your exact case.

From https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html

> **During a network partition**
>
> While a network partition is in place, the two (or more!) sides of the
>   cluster can evolve independently, with both sides thinking the other
>   has crashed. Queues, bindings, exchanges can be created or deleted
>   separately. Mirrored queues which are split across the partition will
>   end up with one master on each side of the partition, again with both
>   sides acting independently.

Some example scenarios:

If queues were created during the network partition, when the cluster is repaired, there is no guarantee that they will be kept. The losing partition will discard its state and restore it from the winning partition.

If you restarted ram nodes, which had the only copy of your queue definitions, then they will be lost. The rabbitmq documentation recommends using no ram nodes for this reason.

I highly recommend the rabbitmq documentation, it's pretty extensive and very precise.

Comment: This is called "split brain", the worst scenario for a cluster ;-( Advanced cluster system such as Zookeeper, Elasticsearch add "master quorum" concept to avoid it. You could monitor all your rabbitmq nodes to check an eventual split brain (by using API).